# Iam new to computer vision...I need to display an image in a window using computer vision program and also drawing functions in opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to write a program in Jupitelab
In opencv
First of all I import opencv
Then I need a program to show an in image in a window and also to draw a rectangular shape in that image
Then the rectangle has to move vertically

Comment: Riya, please posta a minimal code to reproduce the problem you are facing. StackOverflow is not envisioned as a tutorial site. There are tutorials on OpenCV with Python which you can check and follow to get your assignment done. If you find some obstacle with running your code, then you post here minimal sample to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

import opencv

```
import cv2
```

read and show an image in a window

```
img = cv2.imread('path_of_the_image_file')
cv2.imshow('window name', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

for the rectangle, there exists [`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) function.